# Is there such there frequency reasonance that could through entanglement be used to exchange all the atoms in a field from the frequency here/there

Tags: science-fiction

I am a science fiction writer. In my world there is this space ship that has a drive that has a real time mapper that can map the atomic particle frequency in this space, map the frequency of a far off space and through harmonic resonance move the ship from point A to point B instantaneously. Is that even somewhat like a real possibility? I like my sci-fi stories to sound plausible.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by frequency? particle density? molecular temperature? the particular physical distribution of atoms in space?

Comment: From what I can understand from the question, you're essentially talking about teleportation. Asking whether something sounds plausible in a story is different than whether something sounds possible in real life. It really depends on how scientifically involved the rest of your story is. If the goal is just to provide a reason your ship can teleport, then by all means, there's no reason the resonance technology can't exist in your universe. However, if the technology sticks out like a sore thumb against the rest of the setting, readers might balk. In the end, consistency is most important.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! This question is getting a poor reception. The problem is with the number of unexplained jargon terms, and the unexplained level of hardness you want in your scifi. I have answered for realistic science (the answer is no :( ) but in the future, you should make sure to hammer down whether we're talking Star Wars, Star Trek, Known Physics, or something in between.

Answer (score 4):

Without context, "frequency" and "harmonic resonance" sound like buzzwords.  They do not sound like a realistic means of faster than light travel.  Unless you can say how your universe is different to ours, it doesn't sound like science, it sounds like magic.

In our universe, mapping the atomic particle frequency of separated areas of space will not allow you to use harmonic resonance to travel from the one place to the other.

That's not to say that it couldn't be made to *sound* plausible, but that's as much a matter for Writing SE as Worldbuilding SE.  Here on worldbuilding SE, we'd probably be talking about Alcubierre drives in the real universe, and even then it's debatable if they're actually achievable.

Comment: I'd rather say that it *can* be made plausible on worldbuilding SE : Worldbuilding is about making coherent worlds, and writing plausible stories in coherent worlds is much easier than in ones which are incoherent.

Answer (score 2):

## Nope

The rule of thumb for hard-science scifi is  ***You cannot transmit information faster than the speed of light*.**

I am told information is rigorously defined by people much more informed than me. But it certainly includes things like a string of data, a parcel of money, or the dimensions of a spaceship.

So it doesn't matter what the heck is a "real time mapper" or an "atomic particle frequency" or an "harmonic resonance". Anything that lets you instantaneously move a spaceship from one point to another is prohibited by the rules of physics, and by extension hard scifi.

By the way, (quantum) entanglement is not a get out of jail free card here. This is a common misconception around here, and you will find much better explanations than I can give by using the search bar.